# take an attribute from a list of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

By using `underscore` or `jQuery` I need to take the `maximum id` value incremented by one contained in a list of objects.

The javascript object is a `Backbone.Collection` and it looks like this:

```
this.collection.models = [{attributes: {id: 1, ....}}, {}];
```

I wrote the following code which works, but I would like to know if there are any change to improve it.

Thanks.

```
getId: function () {
  return _.max(
          _.map(
           _.pluck(this.collection.models, 'attributes'), function (attributes) {
              return attributes.id;
    })) + 1;
},
```

Answer (score 2):

_.max accepts an callback iterator function:

```
var next = _.max(list, function(i) { return i.attributes.id; }).attributes.id + 1;
```

I knew it was true for the lodash library, didn't know it was true for underscore.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to soert your collection by id, using the [comparator](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) method.

```
collection.comparator = function(model) {
    return model.id;
}
```

When you set that, your last model is guaranteed to have the largets id.

```
collection.next = function(){
    return this.last().id + 1;
}
```

It would probably better to define these when defining the collection:

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  comparator: function(model) {
    return model.id;
  },
  next: function(){
    return this.last().id + 1;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[***Live demo here***](http://livecoding.io/3854158)

How about this:

```
var result = _.chain(this.collection.models)
    .pluck('attributes')
    .max(function(value) {
        return value.id;
    })
    .value();
```

Comment: Author doesn't need an object, he needs an id incremented by 1.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with simple loops, something like this inside the collection is perfectly acceptable:

```
var max = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < this.models.length; ++i)
    max = this.models[i].id > max ? this.models[i].id : max;
return max + 1;
```

Or like this if you're compelled to use Underscore:

```
var max = 0;
this.each(function(m) {
    max = m.id > max ? m.id : max;
});
return max + 1;
```

Both of those would go inside the collection, touching a collection's `models` array outside the collection is bad manners.

Just because you have all the jQuery and Underscore machinery kicking around doesn't mean that you have to use it everywhere.

Comment: +1, about your second solution: `this.models.each(function(m) {` -> `_.each(this.models, function(m) {`

Comment: @LorraineBernard: Or better, `this.each(...)` since [a bunch of Underscore is mixed into collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods).

Answer (score -1):

```
var max = _.max(this.collection.pluck('id')) + 1;
```

And don't use this:

```
this.collection.models = [{attributes: {id: 1, ....}}, {}];
```

Here is proper way:

```
this.collection.reset([{id: 1}, {id: 2}])
```

Comment: This assumes only the attributes object has an id element, which might be an incorrect assumption.

Comment: @GabrielFlorit Author says "The javascript object is a Backbone.Collection", so it's correct assumption.